# Importing css from a node module required in a plugin file with nuxt js

Tags: css, vue.js, leaflet, nuxt.js

To add the fullscreen button to my leaflet map into nuxt i have installed leaflet.fullscreen package and i have edited my plugin `leaflet.js` like so:

```js
    import Vue from "vue";
    import { LMap, LTileLayer, LMarker, LPolyline } from "vue2-leaflet";
    require("leaflet-routing-machine");
    require("lrm-graphhopper");
    require("leaflet.fullscreen");
```

So i can use it in my main template:

```html
    <template>
     <div>
       <section class="search__page">
         <div id="map-wrap" class="map__wrapper"></div>
       </section>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      import Tmap from "@/utils/TripMap.js";

      export default {
        mounted() {
          this.initTmap();
        },
        data() {
          return {
            mainMap: null,
          },
        methods: {
          initTmap() {
            this.mainMap = new Tmap();
            this.mainMap.load();
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

My class looks like that :

```js
    export default class Tmap {
        constructor() {
            this.map = null;
        }
        load) {
            this.map = L.map("map-wrap", {
            fullscreenControl: true,
            fullscreenControlOptions: {
                position: "topleft"
            }).setView([46.7227062, 2.5046503], 6);
            L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy;TRIP'
            }).addTo(this.map);
        }

        addMarkerOnClick() {
            this.map.addEventListener("click", ev => {
                L.marker(ev.latlng).addTo(this.map);
            });
        }
        getBounds() {
            return this.map.getBounds();
        }
    }
```

So in my main component i don't know how to import the css associated to this fullscreen plugin. I tried :

```html
    <style>
        @import "~/node_modules/leaflet.fullscreen/Control.FullScreen.css";
    </style>
```

That works but it's obviously not the good way to do that. Any idea how to that properly ?

Answer (score 4):

From a quick web research i would say you should be able to access the styles like this:

```css
@import "~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

When you register a global style in your nuxt.config.js the app will load it just once. I assume your build is taking more time than normal due to the `node_modules` path.

```css
// nuxt.config.js
css: ['~/assets/styles/global.css'],
```

You could also give the [nuxt resource loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/style-resources) a try.

Comment: so in this case i should copy the css from my node module into my project ?

Comment: No, when you correctly installed the npm package you should be able to import that into your `global.css` like so: `@import '~leaflet-fullscreen/dist/leaflet.fullscreen.css';` Afterwrads teh styles should be available globally in your App.